# How to create an array for input Data In ROBOT FRAMEWORK

Tags: arrays, collections, global-variables, robotframework, selenium2library

How to create an array for input Data In ROBOT FRAMEWORK

By default table should be like this..,

[image]

After that, click  **Add Device**, then some input I given.

Now rows will be Created like this..
[image]

How can I give input as arrays for this table.

Anyone try to solve this problem

Thank you..!

Comment: Have you looked at the [Collections](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html) library, or the [robot documentation on lists](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#list-variable)? You should be able to answer your question by reading the documentation.

Comment: I'm trying.. but, not get it.   Can you give suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*** Variables ***

@{ARRAY LIST}  | 1  |  3   |   4   |   5   |   6

you can use this reference there,
like:

```
${ARRAY LIST}[0]          #1
${ARRAY LIST}[1]          #3
${ARRAY LIST}[2]          #4
```

you will get output like this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).